# TSLint on javascript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jshint, tslint

I spent many hour getting this to work, still without success...

**The question is: How to use the TSLint on .js file?**

Why? I'm trying to have best possible IDE for writing many JavaScript scripts, used in our internal SW.

My vision:

- I have well documented TypeScript definitions of functions and want to use them in .js.
- I want to import .js file and see the errors on it. TSLint is capable to do type control on .ts, according to .d.ts files. But on .js file, JSHint/ESLint can only see the function names and parametres from .d.ts files. Ok, but it's not enough. There is no type control in .js, which I'm missing.
- Use JSHint/ESLint with TSLint in the same time. Using only few functions from both, but making great combo in the end. (TSLint for types, JSHint/ESLint for the rest)
- Do not allow to use TypeScript keywords in JavaScript.
- Autocomplete in .js from .d.ts. Ok, this is working.

I can code in VSCode, Sublime, NetBeans.

Thank you for an ideas!

Answer (score 0):

We should note that a few years after this question was asked, **[TSLint was announced as being deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534)**. Nobody should use it anymore. [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) is its replacement and successor.

typescript-eslint works natively on `.js` files by default. You can go through the [typescript-eslint Getting Started docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started) to start from scratch. If you'd like to enable [typed rules](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting) on `.js` files, that works too - but will need a bit more configuration.